# MediaStore sort by Folder with CursorLoader

Tags: android, directory, mediastore, android-cursorloader

I understand how to query "music files" from MediaStore with cursor loader. 
I also do not see problem to query specific Album, Genre, Artist for songs. But I have no idea how to query MediaStore for song according to the directory in which they are located.

```
final Uri sourceUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                context, 
                sourceUri, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
```

Also if you can help me to get number of songs in album, genre, etc. in same query it would be great.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Michal, your question and example are confusing. You ask about music, yet your code is about Images.
Anyway, to get the song directory

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
```

so when you have a cursor say c which returns _DATA,

```
  String strpath = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._DATA)));
```

this will return the full path including the song title itself.

To get number of tracks of an album (where c is the cursor returned)

```
            String strnosongs = (c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS)));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you. I also fixed my mistake with images in code.

Answer (score 0):

For current API (18) there is no way to do it with in-build tools. This requires to build something (like own database) to help with this query or use other approach (like use "file browser").

Comment: Hey Michal give me some more explanation about build in tool  @Michal